# Flutter: How can I catch errors from js_dev_runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I try to catch a JavaScript error when playing a sound with [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers). The audioplayers function to play a sound does not throw an error but in the browser log i get `Error: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/`. My IDE prints

```
Error: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 355:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1385:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

I have tried following code which you can find in the [flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors):

```dart
void main() {
  FlutterError.onError = (details) {
    FlutterError.presentError(details);
    debugPrint("FlutterError");
  };
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    debugPrint("PlatformDispatcher");
    return true;
  };
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

However this code does not print anything. How can I catch JavaScript errors of js_dev_runtime?